# Search Posts / Pages with multiple options?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, search, tags

Here is what I am trying to accomplish.  Need to design a website for Alcoholics Anonymous (local Chapter) to search for meetings.

1. Need to search for multiple choices of meetings for example.  Men's meeting, on Monday, in the after noon, which is a open discussion meeting, in the city of Sylvania, Ohio.  Other choices could be the same as above but on a Tuesday in Lima, Ohio, or  Woman's meeting on A Friday in the Morning that is a 12and12 meeting, etc.  You get the idea I hope.
2. Would like to have a drop down box where you could choose the variables, and then have the search kick back to a search results page with meetings that meet the submitted choices.
3. Each search result would link to a post or page for that SPECIFIC meting.

I realize that I may have to buy a plugin to do the search.  Does this sound possible without coding using.

DESPERATELY been looking for something like this.

Thanks, A Friend of Bill's

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a custom post type with custom taxonomies and then allow people to filter the results or do a search.

Failing that, perhaps an event plugin would help. It depends on how much coding you want to do or if you want to try and find a plug and play solution.